# Как правильно накатывать дамп базы в postgres

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

При развертывании дампа postgresql-базы вот такой командой `pg_dump my_base < my_dump`, данные в базе не перезаписались. В приложении, которое использует базу я вижу старые записи, которые были до импорта дампа. Должны ли они перезаписываться или это требует каких-то дополнительных действий? Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pg_dump` не умеет восстанавливать дамп вовсе. `pg_dump` потому так и называется, что он дамп создаёт. stdin при этом игнорируется (ну кроме как для потенциального запроса пароля для подключения)

Для восстановления дампа предварительно снятого с помощью `pg_dump` вам нужен:

- если вы делали текстовый дамп - то `psql database --file path_to_dump`. Или любым другим способом передать команды (а текстовый дамп - это именно простые команды) на выполнение, способов много разных.
- если вы делали дамп в форматах `custom` либо `directory` - то вам нужна утилита `pg_restore`: `pg_restore -d database path_to_dump`

Восстановление из дампа предполагает использование пустой целевой базы. Ничего не перезаписывается.

Comment: в pg_restore ещё подкинуть xlog нужно, а то будет ругаться на "не полный стартовый комплект"

Comment: @erl, с чем-то путаете. pg_restore - для логического дампа, а логический дамп самодостаточен. wal нужен для самой базы и для физического бекапа. Возможно со старыми pg_basebackup как раз путаете?

Comment: Ах, да, наверное.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть дамп, то восстановить его можно очень просто:

```
psql database < dump.sql
```