# Как передать файл с кодом создания бд в postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть файл, где создается база данных, я не хочу писать этот код в командной строке postgres. Как мне передать этот файл постгресу?

Comment: Какими средствами? В хранимой процедуре на постгрессе? в каком-то клиенте? из какой-то своей внешней программы на каком-то ЯП?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1023702/178576 https://stackoverflow.com/q/21776008/4827341